# Getting file contents when using DropzoneJS

Tags: dropzone.js

I really love the DropZoneJS component and am currently wrapping it in an EmberJS component (you can see [demo here](https://ember-cli-dropzonejs.firebaseapp.com)). In any event, the wrapper works just fine but I wanted to listen in on one of Dropzone's events and introspect the file contents (not the meta info like size, lastModified, etc.). The file type I'm dealing with is an XML file and I'd like to look "into" it to validate before sending it.

How can one do that? I would have thought the contents would hang off of the `file` object that you can pick up on many of the events but unless I'm just missing something obvious, it isn't there. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've answer my own question and since others appear interested I'll post my answer here. For a working demo of this you can find it here:

> https://ui-dropzone.firebaseapp.com/demo-local-data

In the demo I've wrapped the Dropzone component in the EmberJS framework but if you look at the code you'll find it's just Javascript code, nothing much to be afraid of. :)

The things we'll do are:

- Get the **file** before the network request

  The key thing we need become familiar with is the HTML5 API. Good news is it is quite simple. Take a look at this code and maybe that's all you need:

  ```
  /**
   * Replaces the XHR's send operation so that the stream can be
   * retrieved on the client side instead being sent to the server.
   * The function name is a little confusing (other than it replaces the "send"
   * from Dropzonejs) because really what it's doing is reading the file and
   * NOT sending to the server.
   */
  _sendIntercept(file, options={}) {
    return new RSVP.Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      if(!options.readType) {
        const mime = file.type;
        const textType = a(_textTypes).any(type => {
          const re = new RegExp(type);
          return re.test(mime);
        });
        options.readType = textType ? 'readAsText' : 'readAsDataURL';
      }
      let reader = new window.FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };
      reader.onerror = () => {
        reject(reader.result);
      };

      // run the reader
      reader[options.readType](file);
    });
  },
  ```

  > https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-dropzone/blob/0.7.2/addon/mixins/xhr-intercept.js#L10-L38

  The code above returns a Promise which resolves once the file that's been dropped into the browser has been "read" into Javascript. This should be very quick as it's all local (do be aware that if you're downloading really large files you might want to "chunk" it ... that's a more advanced topic).
- Hook into **Dropzone**

  Now we need to find somewhere to hook into in Dropzone to read the file contents and *stop* the network request that we no longer need. Since the HTML5 File API just needs a `File` object you'll notice that Dropzone provides all sorts of hooks for that.

  I decided on the "accept" hook because it would give me the opportunity to download the file and validate all in one go (for me it's mainly about drag and dropping XML's and so the content of the file is *a part* of the validation process) and crucially it happens *before* the network request.

  Now it's important you realise that we're "replacing" the `accept` function not *listening* to the event it fires. If we just listened we would still incur a network request. So to **overload* accept we do something like this:

  ```
  this.accept = this.localAcceptHandler; // replace "accept" on Dropzone
  ```

  This will only work if `this` is the **Dropzone** object. You can achieve that by:

  - including it in your `init` hook function
  - including it as part of your instantiation (e.g., `new Dropzone({accept: {...}`)

  Now we've referred to the "localAcceptHandler", let me introduce it to you:

  ```
  localAcceptHandler(file, done) {
    this._sendIntercept(file).then(result => {
      file.contents = result;
      if(typeOf(this.localSuccess) === 'function') {
        this.localSuccess(file, done);
      } else {
        done(); // empty done signals success
      }
    }).catch(result => {
      if(typeOf(this.localFailure) === 'function') {
        file.contents = result;
        this.localFailure(file, done);
      } else {
        done(`Failed to download file ${file.name}`);
        console.warn(file);
      }
    });
  }
  ```

  > https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-dropzone/blob/0.7.2/addon/mixins/xhr-intercept.js#L40-L64

  In quick summary it does the following:

  - read the contents of the file (aka, `_sendIntercept`)
  - based on mime type read the file either via `readAsText` or `readAsDataURL`
  - save the file contents to the `.contents` property of the file
- Stop the **send**

  To intercept the sending of the request on the network but still maintain the rest of the workflow we will replace a function called `submitRequest`. In the Dropzone code this function is a one liner and what I did was replace it with my own one-liner:

  this._finished(files,'locally resolved, refer to "contents" property');

  > https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-dropzone/blob/0.7.2/addon/mixins/xhr-intercept.js#L66-L70
- Provide **access** to retrieved document

  The last step is just to ensure that our `localAcceptHandler` is put *in place of* the `accept` routine that dropzone supplies:

  > https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-dropzone/blob/0.7.2/addon/components/drop-zone.js#L88-L95

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me:

```
Dropzone.options.PDFDrop = {
    maxFilesize: 10, // Mb
    accept: function(file, done) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(event) { console.log(event.target.result);});
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
};
```

could also use `reader.reaAsBinaryString()` if binary data!

Comment: I agree. Keeping it simple: not adding done() in the accept function prevents the upload.

Comment: Using vue-clip, my file object has no content, whatever I do I always get this error: "TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsText does not implement interface Blob"

Comment: So anyone found a solution for that `TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsText does not implement interface Blob` ?

Answer (score 0):

using the FileReader() solution is working amazingly good for me:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var dz = new Dropzone("#demo-upload",{
   autoProcessQueue:false,
   url:'upload.php'
});

dz.on("drop",function drop(e) {
              var files = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
                files[i] = e.dataTransfer.files[i];
              }


var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
    var line = event.target.result.split('\n');
    for ( var i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
        console.log(line);
    }
};
reader.readAsText(files[files.length-1]);
```